# Filepicker.io - upload/store file after choosing export destination

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

In my web app, I'm generating some large image files and would like the user to be able to export them using filepicker.io
My problem is that it seems I have to call `filepicker.store` to upload the generated file BEFORE I call `filepicker.exportFile`, but I want to upload the file AFTER the user has chosen a destination. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not the most elegant mechanism, you can use the fact that filepicker urls are read/write to store a "temporary" image using the exportFile call. You can then take the FPFile object that is returned and do a filepicker.write() call to store the file after the destination has been chosen.

Comment: I was thinking something like this, but wanted to make sure there wasn't a more elegant way of doing it. It would be nice if Filepicker had a way of queueing files to be exported. It would make working with large files a smoother experience, especially on the user's end. But, storing a temp file should work well for my needs. Thanks!